# Blazor Server on DotNetCore 3.1 Calling a Javascript File

Tags: javascript, blazor

I have a running site, using Blazer Server 3.1 The customer wants a change and for that I have to call a Javascript function.

I created the function in wwwroot and in _Host.cshmtl I added a reference **before** the call to ...framework/blazor.server.js

My form is called from the Index.razor component. I've added the code:

```
 protected override void OnInitialized()
   // protected async override void OnInitialized()
    {
        JS.InvokeVoidAsync("~/pixel");
        var uri = NavManager.ToAbsoluteUri(NavManager.Uri);
        base.OnInitialized();
    }
```

I am injecting the IJSRuntime interface.

The call to Javascript is not working

When I publish my site I am getting some 404 on the javascript file and even on an image that is in css/pictures, basically my css is all gone...

I can see the reference to the javascript in the body and I've checked the Javascript code and it does not return an error...

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Forgot to mention that the site is a subdomain

Comment: The call to InvokeVoidAsync looks funny.  Typically the first parameter should be the name of the js method.  Can you please share the js code you are trying to call?

Comment: I've tried several things, the first parameter is the file name. I've tried the js code with a "function(... " and just the js code neither worked.

Comment: My concern is that this site is a subdomain and I am referring to my assets the wrong way...

Comment: Here is the js code, it does not return anything. What is does is that it adds some functionality to the body which will trigger a web app when the site is reached.  var ordnumber = Math.random() * 10000000000000; var sscUrl = ("https:" == document.location.protocol ? "https://" : "http://") + "trkn.us/pixel/conv/ppt=12829;g=mortgage-protection-letters;gid=35013;ord=" + ordnumber + ";v=120"; var x = document.createElement("img"); x.setAttribute("src", sscUrl); x.setAttribute("width", "1"); x.setAttribute("height", "1"); document.body.appendChild(x);

Comment: Paul please post your code inside of the question so it is more readable.  At a minimum please show the entire method your are calling.  It may also be helpful to show parts of your host.cshtml file

Comment: Hey Jason, I am rewriting the code as a new domain. I have this up and running today, I'll try and come back here, after I put out this fire. From what I read online it may be difficult to create a subdomain in blazors server. I have the domain ABC.COM (just an example) already running for several customers, one of them wants some personalization and I thought that the natural thing would be to create (example) ACustomer.ABC.com but this creates a bunch of 404. Regardless thanks for helping

Comment: Jason, I found out why my app is not working. I am hosting the app with an ISP that "supports" Dotnet Core 3.1.  They actually offshore their "windows" support. The first Blazor app that I wrote (and is working fine) is under "HTTPDOCS" which is the "root" for my site.  I wrote a couple of web api apps which are working fine. This is the second Blazor app that I am now writing and I am getting a bunch of 404 (not only for the image but also for site.css, bootstrap.min etc.., So it is an architecture problem. I've tried modifying baseurl but all my efforts were not successful.

Comment: I am now thinking that I have to rewrite the app using another language.
I just asked the question to Microsoft support and was told that they do not support this environment..

Comment: I login through PLESK and I can see the non Blazor sites as well as HTTPDOCS, I have them create another site which is at the same level as HTTPDOCS (just clarifying)